# Ios app works fine on simulator / devices through xcode but stuck on splash during apple review

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created 1 app in cordova framework for ios platform.
When checked on simulator and also on tab and iphone it works as expected.
But after submiting to for appstore distribution it stuck on splash screen during apple review.
On splash screen i am just showing basic loader functionality and device registratio  api is getting called.
If issue in api it was not suppose to work at my end also.
Kindly help not getting where i am wrong

Comment: Have you tested a TestFlight build on a device that doesn't have your app installed?  Have you tested on a device with no network connection? Have you tested on a device with a pure ipv6 network connection?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience submitting apps to the App Store, I suggest three options:

1. Test the build in TestFlight and ensure that the flow is running correctly (apps can actually break before submitting the build to the App Store)
2. Ensure the API address is available in all countries (Apple testers are from different locations, if they are unable to access the API and the app breaks, this may be grounds for rejection).
3. Ensure your app complies with the App Store Review Guidelines (worth reading): https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/